# Data parsed from Json cant fetch properly when add another argument in constructor

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, parcelable

This is Fist time i'm asking question!! so bear with me.
The application is project(popular movie stage 2) from udacity where i need to fetch info of movies like tilte or poster_path or backdrop_path.

so when i fetch data from json it works perfectly fine but when i add another argument  `String backdrop` in my `Movies.java` class.then `getmBackdrop()` shows empty and i couldn't get the data of backdrop overview and vote.but if i delete backdrop from constructor than it works fine. i dont know what is happening please help me.

this is `Movies.java`class

```
public class Movies implements Parcelable {


    //Movies Data
    public  long mID;
    private String mPosterPath;
    private String mReleaseDate;
    private String mTitle;
    private String mVote;
    private String mOverview;
    private String mBackdrop;
    private ArrayList<Trailers> trailers;
    private ArrayList<Reviews> reviews;

    public Movies() {

    }

    public Movies(String title, String releaseDate, String posterPath,
                  String backdrop,String vote, String overview) {
       // this.mID=id;
        this.mTitle = title;
        this.mReleaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.mPosterPath = posterPath;
        this.mBackdrop = backdrop;
        this.mVote = vote;
        this.mOverview = overview;
        this.trailers = new ArrayList<>();
        this.reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    }
    public long  getID(){ return mID ;}


    public String getmBackdrop() { return mBackdrop; }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return mPosterPath;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return mReleaseDate;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return mOverview;
    }

    public String getVote() {
        return mVote +"/10";
    }

    public void setTrailers(ArrayList<Trailers> trailers) {
        this.trailers = trailers;
    }

    public void setReviews(ArrayList<Reviews> reviews) {
        this.reviews = reviews;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeLong(mID);
        dest.writeString(mTitle);
        dest.writeString(mReleaseDate);
        dest.writeString(mPosterPath);
        dest.writeValue(mBackdrop);
        dest.writeString(mVote);
        dest.writeString(mOverview);
    }

    protected Movies(Parcel in) {
        mID = in.readLong();
        mTitle = in.readString();
        mReleaseDate = in.readString();
        mPosterPath = in.readString();
        mBackdrop = in.readString();
        mVote = in.readString();
        mOverview = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Movies> CREATOR = new Creator<Movies>() {
        public Movies createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Movies(source);
        }

        public Movies[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Movies[size];
        }
    };
}
```

`MoviepediaJsonUtils.java` where i'm parsing data

```
public class MoviepediaJsonUtils {
    public static ArrayList<Movies> getParseMovieJson(String jsonMovies) throws JSONException {


        final String IMAGE_BASE_URL = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
        final String BACKDROP_URL= "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280/";

        JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(jsonMovies);
        JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray("results");

        ArrayList<Movies> movieArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject movieObject = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);

            long id = movieObject.getLong("id");
            String title = movieObject.getString("title");
            String release_date = movieObject.getString("release_date");
            String poster_path = movieObject.getString("poster_path");
            String backdrop = movieObject.getString("backdrop_path");
            String vote_average = movieObject.getString("vote_average");
            String overview = movieObject.getString("overview");


            Movies movies = new Movies(title, release_date,
                    IMAGE_BASE_URL + poster_path, BACKDROP_URL+backdrop,vote_average, overview);

            movieArrayList.add(movies);
        }

        return movieArrayList;
    }

    public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stream);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

        boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
        if (hasInput) {
            return scanner.next();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}



MainActivityFragments.java 

public class MainActivityFragments extends Fragment {
    private static final int COLUMN = 2;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    SharedPreferences mSettings;
    GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager;

    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    private static final String SHARED_KEY_SORT = "sort";
    private static final String POPULARITY = "popular";
    private static final String RATINGS = "top_rated";
    public static String[] backdrop;

    public static final String SAVE_LAST_UPDATE_ORDER = "save_last_update_order";
    private String mLastUpdateOrder;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.poster_fragment, container, false);
        if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
            mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        }else{
            mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        }
        mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_movies);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
        mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mEditor = mSettings.edit();
        mEditor.apply();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Movies>()));


        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (needToUpdateUi()) {
            updateUi();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(SAVE_LAST_UPDATE_ORDER, mLastUpdateOrder);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mLastUpdateOrder = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_LAST_UPDATE_ORDER);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        updateUi();
    }


    //   OnCreateOptionMenues  will be here
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.poster_fragment, menu);
        Drawable drawable = menu.findItem(R.id.icon).getIcon();
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
    }


    //  OnOptionitemSelected
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.poularity:
                mEditor.putString(SHARED_KEY_SORT, POPULARITY);
                mEditor.apply();
                updateUi();
                item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
            case R.id.top_rated:
                mEditor.putString(SHARED_KEY_SORT, RATINGS);
                mEditor.apply();
                updateUi();
                item.setChecked(true);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        String sortBy = mSettings.getString(SHARED_KEY_SORT, POPULARITY);
        if (sortBy.equals(POPULARITY)) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.poularity).setChecked(true);
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.top_rated).setChecked(true);
        }
    }

    private void updateUi() {
        if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
            OnTaskCompleted taskCompleted = new OnTaskCompleted() {
                @Override
                public void onFetchMoviesTaskCompleted(ArrayList<Movies> movies) {
                    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MoviesAdapter(getActivity(), movies));
                }
            };
            MoviesAsyncTask moviesAsyncTask = new MoviesAsyncTask(taskCompleted);
            mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());


            String sortBy = mSettings.getString(SHARED_KEY_SORT, POPULARITY);
            mLastUpdateOrder = sortBy;
            moviesAsyncTask.execute(sortBy);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Need Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }



    private boolean needToUpdateUi() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        if (!mLastUpdateOrder.equals(prefs.getString(SHARED_KEY_SORT, POPULARITY))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    //Based on a stackoverflow snippet
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) this.getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

}

DeatailActivityFragment

public class DetailActivityFragments extends Fragment {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();




    private static final String PARCEL_KEY = "movie_parcel";
    Movies mMovie;
    OnTaskCompleted mlistener;
    ArrayList<Trailers> mTrailers;
    ArrayList<Reviews> mReviews;
    ImageView poster;
    ImageView backdrop;
    public DetailActivityFragments() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_detail_fragment,
                container, false);
        Movies parceableExtra = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra(PARCEL_KEY);

        poster = view.findViewById(R.id.poster_IV);
        TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.title_TV);
        TextView releaseDate = view.findViewById(R.id.relaesedate_TV);
        TextView vote = view.findViewById(R.id.vote_TV);
        TextView overView = view.findViewById(R.id.overview_TV);
        backdrop = view.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
        final FloatingActionButton fab1 = view.findViewById(R.id.fab);

        //String gotPosition = getStringExtra("position");
        //intGotPosition=Integer.parseInt(gotPosition);
       // String url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w1280"+DetailActivityFragments.backdrop[intGotPosition];

        title.setText(parceableExtra.getTitle());
        releaseDate.setText(parceableExtra.getReleaseDate());
        vote.setText(parceableExtra.getVote());
        overView.setText(parceableExtra.getOverview());

        Picasso.with(view.getContext()).load(parceableExtra.getPosterPath())
                .into(poster);

        Picasso.with(this.getActivity()).load( parceableExtra.getmBackdrop())
                .error(R.drawable.sam).into(backdrop);


        fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context context = view.getContext();
                Intent i=new Intent(context , TrailerActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

MoviesAsyncTask.java

```
public class MoviesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Movies>>  {


    private final String LOG_TAG = MoviesAsyncTask.class.getSimpleName();
    final String MY_API_KEY = "removed deliberately";
    ArrayList<Movies> mMovies;
    private OnTaskCompleted mListener;

    public MoviesAsyncTask(OnTaskCompleted listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Movies> doInBackground(String... params) {


        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

            final String MOVIEDB_BASE_URL =
                    "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/";
            final String APIKEY = "api_key";


            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(MOVIEDB_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendPath(params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(APIKEY, MY_API_KEY)
                    .build();


            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            URLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                connection = url.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String response = null;
            try {
                response = MoviepediaJsonUtils.getResponseFromHttpUrl(connection.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                return MoviepediaJsonUtils.getParseMovieJson(response);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Movies> movies) {
        super.onPostExecute(movies);
        mListener.onFetchMoviesTaskCompleted(movies);
        mMovies = movies;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am curious as to why you have used `dest.writeValue(mBackdrop);` instead of `dest.writeString(mBackdrop);` in your `writeToParcel` method

Comment: In my mind, I was sure that I wrote `dest.writeString(mBackdrop) ` i think that was the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add your string at the end of your class or remove all the parcelable generated code, add your string, then apply again the parcelable implementation.

This happens because you're not updating the parcel methods.

Comment: string at the end of your class?? what does it mean please clarify this and should I remove all the parceable code and write again in movies.java?

Comment: When you add `String backdrop` to the constructor of `Movies` class, you should also add it the parcelable methods

Comment: Thank you very much ... it's working now ... thanks again